# adding a ggplot2 stat_function to an existing graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a graph and I'd like to superimpose a functional form over the graph. Seems straight forward, but I'm missing something. Here's my example data and illustration where I use `stat_function` to try and add `f1` to the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
sample_data <- data.frame(rate  = c(0.514492753623188, 0.553072625698324, 0.656527249683143, 0.675694939415538,
                                    0.68681076312307, 0.715657311669128, 0.792349726775956), 
                          level = c(0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85) )

f1 <- function(x) pbeta(x, shape1=1.01, shape2=.9 ) * 100

g <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = rate*100 , x = level), 
            data = sample_data, stat="identity") +
  stat_function(fun = f1) 
g
```

[image]

As you can see, the `f1` line is not there.

So as an alternative, I can add the points to the initial data.frame and then plot them with `geom_line` as the following example illustrates:

```
## add f1 to data.frame
sample_data$f1 <- f1(sample_data$level )

g <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = rate*100 , x = level), 
            data = sample_data, stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = f1 , x = level), 
   data = sample_data, stat="identity", color='red')
g
```

[image]

So that works, and gets me what I need, but I can't figure out why `stat_function` didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `data = sample_data, aes(y = rate*100 , x = level)` in your first `ggplot` call so `stat_function` knows about the data are being used

```r
library(ggplot2)

sample_data <- data.frame(rate  = c(0.514492753623188, 0.553072625698324, 0.656527249683143, 0.675694939415538,
                                    0.68681076312307, 0.715657311669128, 0.792349726775956), 
                          level = c(0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85) )

f1 <- function(x) pbeta(x, shape1=1.01, shape2=.9 ) * 100

g <- ggplot(data = sample_data, aes(y = rate*100 , x = level)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_function(fun = f1, color = "red")
g
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: ohhh. I get it. Thank you, I didn't realize the implications of where I put my `data=` step.

Comment: You're welcome! Also you don't need `stat="identity"` in `geom_line()` either

Comment: that makes sense... I had originally been making some bar charts and the identity business sort of stuck to my code ;)

Comment: That was my guess as well :D